# Angular single page application throws 404 error on Refresh

Tags: angular, routes, pagepiling.js

I am using "pagepilling.js" for my Angular single-page angular application. When I refresh the page after routing from one component to another component. It will be thrown me an error with a **404** code.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Comment: Does that happen with ng serve or with deployed code? If the latter - you need to solve that on the server (i.e rewrite all requests to non-existing resources back to index.html)

Comment: Yes, it's a classic problem. When you reach your application on `localhost:8000/` (or whatever your port is), your back-end is configured to serve you the `index.html`. Good. Then, the Angular app starts up, and does its routing. It rewrites the URL to, say, `localhost:8000/users/joe`. Now, when you reload the page, you are asking your back-end the route `/users/joe`. Out of the box, the back-end has no idea what to do with this route, so it sends a 404. You have to configure it to redirect anything unknown to `/`, so it serves `index.html`.

Comment: Rewrite, not redirect.. :-)

Comment: Definitely nothing to do with pagePiling.js :)